# How use original bundle collection into area MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a MVC5 website with one area called Freemium. I used bundles collection for my entire website and everything works really well except when I open the freemium area. All of my jquery and css files are not load! I try to figure out the problem and the only solution I found is to copy all the css and jquery files into the area folder but I don't want to do that because that will always be the same files copy & paste.

So when I render the css and js with

```
@Styles.Render("~/Freemium/Content/metro-ui/css")
```

I get the error:

> The controller for path '/Freemium/Content/metro-ui/css' was not found or does not implement IController.
>   Stack trace:
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)**

Here it's the bundles I need to make working in the freemium area.

```
private static BundleCollection SetMetroUIFreemiumBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // CSS
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Freemium/Content/metro-ui/css/metrocss")
            .Include("~/Content/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap.css"
            , "~/Content/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css"
            , "~/Content/metro-ui/css/iconFont.min.css"));

        // Scripts
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Freemium/Scripts/metro-ui/metrojs")
            .Include("~/Scripts/metro-ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"
            , "~/Scripts/metro-ui/metro.min.js"));

        return bundles;
    }
```

Comment: It's been a while since I created an MVC site, but shouldn't it be `@Styles.Render("~/Freemium/Content/metro-ui/css/metrocss")`?

Comment: OMG, I work for too long I have not seen my path error. Thank you very much!! I'll take a break!!

Comment: I added this comment as the answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I created an MVC site, but shouldn't it be

```
@Styles.Render("~/Freemium/Content/metro-ui/css/metrocss")
```

The `Render("path")` path should match the `new StyleBundle("path")`.